# Handing csv dataset in ajax response is drving me nuts

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am certain that I am missing something simple here but this is driving me crazy!

So, I have a Python cgi script that is parsing a PDF file and returning data to an Ajax call. I can see the response data using FireFox tools. The problem is when I try to extract the data from that object, I am getting a TypeError:  is undefined.

So, I copied that same code into another file, without the Ajax call, and it works just fine!

Here is the non-ajax code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
function f1 ()
{
var data ={contributions: ',01/08/2013,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\n,01/23/2013,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\n,02/05/2013,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\n,02/20/2013,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\n,03/05/2013,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\n,03/19/2013,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\n', 'transactions': 'TSPGF,01/08/2013,Contribution,$165.60,$0.00,$165.60,14.0268,11.8060\nTSPGF,01/23/2013,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.0354,11.7988\nTSPGF,02/05/2013,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.0431,11.7922\nTSPGF,02/20/2013,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.0526,11.7842\nTSPGF,03/05/2013,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.0605,11.7777\nTSPGF,03/19/2013,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.0685,11.7710\nTSPCF,01/08/2013,Contribution,$193.20,$0.00,$193.20,18.4276,10.4842\nTSPCF,01/23/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,18.9105,10.2166\nTSPCF,02/05/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,19.1302,10.0992\nTSPCF,02/20/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,19.1673,10.0797\nTSPCF,03/05/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,19.5376,9.8887\nTSPCF,03/19/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,19.6652,9.8244\nTSPIF,01/08/2013,Contribution,$193.20,$0.00,$193.20,21.0409,9.1821\nTSPIF,01/23/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,21.4478,9.0080\nTSPIF,02/05/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,21.7097,8.8992\nTSPIF,02/20/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,21.6849,8.9094\nTSPIF,03/05/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,21.7807,8.8702\nTSPIF,03/19/2013,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,21.8995,8.8221\n'};
f2(data);
f3(data);

}
function f2(data)
{
    var c1=data.contributions;
    var c2=c1.split("\n");
    str="<table>";
        for (i=0; i< c2.length; i++)
        {
            ss = c2[i].trim().split(",");
            str += "<tr>";
            for (j=0; j<ss.length; j++)
            {
                str += "<td>";
                str += ss[j];
                str += "</td>";
            }
            str += "</tr>";
        }
        str += "</table>";
       document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = str;

}
function f3(data)
{
   var c1=data.transactions;
   var c2=c1.split("\n");
    str="<table>";
        for (i=0; i< c2.length; i++)
        {
            ss = c2[i].trim().split(",");
            str += "<tr>";
            for (j=0; j<ss.length; j++)
            {
                str += "<td>";
                str += ss[j];
                str += "</td>";
            }
            str += "</tr>";
        }
        str += "</table>";
   document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = str;
}
window.onload = function ()
{
  f1();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The data in f1() is what I get back from the server side.

My ajax code is -

```
   var data = new FormData(form);
   var xht= new XMLHttpRequest();
   xht.open(form.method, form.action, true);
   xht.send(data);

    xht.onreadystatechange = function (response) {
            if (xht.readyState == 4 && xht.status === 200) {
                    showCSV(xht.responseText);
    }
    function showCSV (cont)
    {
            tab = document.getElementById("csvContent");
            var c1 = cont.contributions;
            var c2 = c1.split("\n");
            str="<table>";
            for (i=0; i< c2.length; i++)
            {
                ss = c2[i].trim().split(",");
                str += "<tr>";
                for (j=0; j<ss.length; j++)
                {
                    str += "<td>";
                    str += ss[j];
                    str += "</td>";
                }
                str += "</tr>";
            }
            str += "</table>";
      tab.innerHTML=str
    }
```

When I run this same function in my real code, I get TypeError: cont.contributions undefined

What am I missing?

Thanks
RD

Edit:
console.log(response) gives -

```
response: " \r\n    {'contributions': ',01/07/2014,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\\n,01/22/2014,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\\n,02/04/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n,02/19/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n,03/04/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n,03/18/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n', 'transactions': 'TSPGF,01/07/2014,Contribution,$165.60,$0.00,$165.60,14.2937,11.5856\\nTSPGF,01/22/2014,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.3085,11.5736\\nTSPGF,02/04/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3212,12.8487\\nTSPGF,02/19/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3344,12.8369\\nTSPGF,03/04/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3460,12.8265\\nTSPGF,03/18/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3584,12.8155\\nTSPCF,01/07/2014,Contribution,$193.20,$0.00,$193.20,23.7450,8.1364\\nTSPCF,01/22/2014,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,23.8509,8.1003\\nTSPCF,02/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,22.6981,9.4580\\nTSPCF,02/19/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,23.6926,9.0610\\nTSPCF,03/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,24.2968,8.8358\\nTSPCF,03/18/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,24.2999,8.8346\\nTSPIF,01/07/2014,Contribution,$193.20,$0.00,$193.20,25.2897,7.6394\\nTSPIF,01/22/2014,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,25.6717,7.5258\\nTSPIF,02/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,24.1165,8.9018\\nTSPIF,02/19/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,25.5346,8.4074\\nTSPIF,03/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,25.7334,8.3424\\nTSPIF,03/18/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,25.3494,8.4689\\n'} \r\n    \r\n"
​​
responseText: " \r\n    {'contributions': ',01/07/2014,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\\n,01/22/2014,Contribution,276.00,0.00,55.20,220.80,552.00\\n,02/04/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n,02/19/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n,03/04/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n,03/18/2014,Contribution,306.68,0.00,61.34,245.35,613.37\\n', 'transactions': 'TSPGF,01/07/2014,Contribution,$165.60,$0.00,$165.60,14.2937,11.5856\\nTSPGF,01/22/2014,Contribution,165.60,0.00,165.60,14.3085,11.5736\\nTSPGF,02/04/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3212,12.8487\\nTSPGF,02/19/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3344,12.8369\\nTSPGF,03/04/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3460,12.8265\\nTSPGF,03/18/2014,Contribution,184.01,0.00,184.01,14.3584,12.8155\\nTSPCF,01/07/2014,Contribution,$193.20,$0.00,$193.20,23.7450,8.1364\\nTSPCF,01/22/2014,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,23.8509,8.1003\\nTSPCF,02/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,22.6981,9.4580\\nTSPCF,02/19/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,23.6926,9.0610\\nTSPCF,03/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,24.2968,8.8358\\nTSPCF,03/18/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,24.2999,8.8346\\nTSPIF,01/07/2014,Contribution,$193.20,$0.00,$193.20,25.2897,7.6394\\nTSPIF,01/22/2014,Contribution,193.20,0.00,193.20,25.6717,7.5258\\nTSPIF,02/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,24.1165,8.9018\\nTSPIF,02/19/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,25.5346,8.4074\\nTSPIF,03/04/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,25.7334,8.3424\\nTSPIF,03/18/2014,Contribution,214.68,0.00,214.68,25.3494,8.4689\\n'} \r\n    \r\n"
​​
responseType: ""
```

New edit:

I am wondering if the newlines before and after the data are the cause of problem. I sent a blank message from the cgi and I see this in FF -

```
response: " \r\n \r\n\r\n"
responseText: " \r\n \r\n\r\n"
```

The python cgi code that returns the data is -

```
if csv :
    a = """Content-Type: text/csv\n\n 
    {} 
    """
    print (a.format(csv))
else :
    a = """Content-Type: text/plain\n\n 
    {} 
    """
    print (a.format(message)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It seems it has something to do with JSON or data being returned .Show the screenshot of response?

Comment: have no duplicated your code but my first guess would be that your return comes back as an array instead of a plain object. Have you tried cont[0].contributions?

Comment: `console.log(response)` and `console.log(typeof(response))` right before you call `showCSV()` to see what you're working with. You might just need to json.parse() the response.